# Kotlin : Save Image to database

Tags: image, sqlite, kotlin

I am creating user profile in kotlin, 
I want to give the users two option (select from avatar or capture image)
then save profile in "sqlite" database

what is the best solution ?

if you help me in code I will be thankful

Comment: what you ask is actually good, but next time try to include the code that you have created, because stack overflow is a place to ask how things work, not to give a solution to how to make something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution for that:

**Create Database class "DatabaseHelper.kt":**

```
 class DatabaseHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1) {

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {

    db.execSQL("Create Table $TABLE_NAME(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Category_img BLOB)")

}

override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME)
    onCreate(db)
}


fun insertData(Category_img: ByteArray): Boolean {
    val db = writableDatabase
    val cv = ContentValues()
    cv.put(CAL_NO1, Category_img)


    val result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv)

    return if (result .equals( -1))
        false
    else
        true


}


fun getdata(): ByteArray {
    val db = writableDatabase
    val res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null)

    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            return res.getBlob(0)
        } while (res.moveToNext())
    }
    return byteArrayOf()
}

companion object {
    private val DATABASE_NAME = "user.db"
    private val TABLE_NAME = "tbl_user"
    private val CAL_NO1 = "Category_img"
}

}
```

**and do code this from where you want to access Camera:**

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  var dbSq: DatabaseHelper= DatabaseHelper(this);



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 101)


}

public override fun onActivityResult(requestcode: Int, resultcode: Int, intent: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, intent)
    if (resultcode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestcode == 101) {


            val photo = intent.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
            val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
            val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()

            Log.d("check",dbSq.insertData(byteArray).toString().plus(" "));

        }
    }
}
```

### Edited

**"DatabaseHelper.kt":**

```
class DatabaseHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1) {

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {

    db.execSQL("Create Table $TABLE_NAME(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Category_img Text)")

}

override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME)
    onCreate(db)
}


fun insertData(Category_img: String): Boolean {
    val db = writableDatabase
    val cv = ContentValues()
    cv.put(CAL_NO1, Category_img)


    val result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv)

    return if (result .equals( -1))
        false
    else
        true


}




companion object {
    private val DATABASE_NAME = "user.db"
    private val TABLE_NAME = "tbl_user"
    private val CAL_NO1 = "Category_img"
}

}
```

**and do code this from where you want to access Camera:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var dbSq: DatabaseHelper= DatabaseHelper(this);

internal var output: File? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

    val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)

    val date = Date()
    output = File(dir, "CheckImage " + date.toString()+".jpeg")

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 101)


}

public override fun onActivityResult(requestcode: Int, resultcode: Int, intent: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, intent)
    if (resultcode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestcode == 101) {





            Log.d("check",dbSq.insertData(output!!.absolutePath).toString().plus(" "));

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, can I save the photo in the device and save filename on database, or save it in database is the best solution?

Comment: You save it in device and its name in database this is best solution i think.My answer is just according to your requirement. If you want to save it in device and name in database thats also ok.

Comment: See my EDited Code::

Comment: sure it's what I am looking for .. it work with me, may thanks